# cordova compile Android error platform.version is not a function

Tags: cordova

While compiling project on Cordova using command `cordova compile Android` it is giving me error:

> platform.version is not a function

Could anyone please help regarding this? I have tried to remove android file and then again adding it but it still doesn't work.

I have updated the plugins too but it didn't help. I looked up for `platform.version` function in any files but there is nothing.

Comment: It would be "cordova build android"

Comment: Yes I have used “cordova build android” and the android project file is getting created but for creating APK I need to use “Cordova compile android” I have every environment variable set in my zshrc file still getting error

Comment: build = prepare + compile. Make sure your prepare 1st

Comment: Could you please elaborate the solution